# FaceRec tutorial explanation

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I try to do [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html?highlight=subspacereconstruct) face recognition example, with Eigenfaces. And cannot understand what these functions *subspaceProject()* and *subspaceReconstruct()* actually do. I tried to search on http://docs.opencv.org/ but there was not any link to description.

Could you explain me what this part of the code actually do?

```
Mat evs = Mat(W, Range::all(), Range(0, num_components));
Mat projection = subspaceProject(evs, mean, images[0].reshape(1,1));
Mat reconstruction = subspaceReconstruct(evs, mean, projection);
    // Normalize the result:
reconstruction = norm_0_255(reconstruction.reshape(1, images[0].rows));
```

I mean what these functions do, what kind of cv::Mat they return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subspaceProject()` will basically give you a dimensionality reduction.

```
projection = (images[0] - mean) * evs
```

Subtracting the mean ensures that the images approximate a subspace.
Presumably evs is the truncated right singular vectors.

and for `subspaceReconstruct()`

```
reconstruction = projection * transpose(evs) + mean
```

The reconstruction is just the reverse of the projection, except since evs is truncated, it can not be perfect.

See [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Dimensionality_reduction)